# What is the XPath for the menu items on this site?

Tags: python, html

http://caldining.berkeley.edu/menus/cafe3#day1

Each item is contained in Oatmeal

but //p[@class="item_list"] does not work..

Comment: Not really a code related issue but the `xpath` for Oatmeal is `//*[@id="node-179"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/p[1]/a` Each subsequent Oatmeal just increases `div[4]` by `1`

Comment: what means "does not work" ? Do you get wrong results or error message ? Maybe show your code.

Answer (score 0):

This `xpath` works for me if I use `lxml`

```
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'http://caldining.berkeley.edu/menus/cafe3#day1'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)

for x in soup.xpath('//p[@class="item_list"]/a'):
    print(x.text)
```

But maybe you use `BeautifulSoup` which doesn't have function `xpath()` but it doesn't raise error like `"function xpath doesn't exists"` but "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" which looks like `xpath()` exists but returns `None`.

But works `find_all` and `select()`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'http://caldining.berkeley.edu/menus/cafe3#day1'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BS(r.content, 'lxml')

for x in soup.xpath('//p[@class="item_list"]/a'): # ERROR
#for x in soup.find_all('p', class_='item_list'): # OK
#for x in soup.select('p.item_list a'): # OK
    print(x.text)
```